# Saída inesperada ao imprimir substring

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, substring, awk

Estou fazendo uma busca de arquivos num determinado diretório e imprimindo o seu respectivo `path`.

```
find ./ -exec sh -c "echo $(dirname "{}")" \;
```

Output:

```
./algo/desse/tipo
```

Visto que em alguns casos esse `path` é um pouco grande, resolvi pegar somente o diretório pai, nesse caso a substring `algo`.

Para isso, tentei os seguintes comandos abaixo:

```
dirname "{}" | awk -F"/" '{ print $2 }'

dirname "{}" | sed "s/\(\/\.*\/\)/\1/"

dirname "{}" | cut -d'/' -f2
```

Porém, nenhum deles me retornou o resultado esperado. O `awk` me retorna em branco enquanto que o `sed` e o `cut` me retorna literalmente um ponto (`.`).

---

Esse é o comando que quero rodar:

```
find ./ -regex '\./.*_.*\.\(doc\|docx\|md\|xls\)$' -exec sh -c '

    status=$(stat -c "%.10w;%.10y;$(dirname "{}");$(basename "{}")" "{}") 

    if{something}

' \;
```

Para cada resultado do find já estou imprimindo uma linha formatada, o problema é que no comando `dirname` se eu adiciono o pipe `| awk -F"/" '{ print $2 }'` ele não muda o meu resultado.

- O que posso estar fazendo de errado??
- É algo relacionado ao uso das aspas simples??
- Existe uma forma melhor de conseguir a informação de que preciso?

Comment: seus scripts estão confusos...mostre um exemplo concreto...faça como eu fiz em minha resposta: mostre uma listagem dos diretórios e arquivos, e as linhas que você quer como resultado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode chamar o `awk` diretamente na saída de `find`, sem precisar do `exec`:

```
find ./  | awk -F"/" '{print $2}'
```

Só que `find ./` também inclui o diretório atual, o que quer dizer que ele também retorna `./` nos seus resultados. E ao passar isso para o `awk`, ele acaba imprimindo uma linha em branco (já que neste caso não tem nada depois da barra).

Se quiser, você pode contornar isso com um `if`:

```
find ./  | awk -F"/" '{if ($2) { print $2 } else { print $1 } }'
```

Assim, o diretório atual (que o `find` retorna como `./`) será impresso como `.`, e os demais diretórios serão impressos normalmente.

---

Mas esta solução ainda gera muita repetição. Se você tem vários arquivos no mesmo diretório, por exemplo, o nome deste diretório será impresso várias vezes.

Você pode eliminar as repetições usando `sort` (para ordenar os resultados) e em seguida com [`uniq`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uniq.1.html) (que elimina linhas seguidas que são iguais):

```
find ./  | awk -F"/" '{if ($2) { print $2 } else { print $1 } }' |sort |uniq
```

Por fim, você pode usar a opção `-c`, que faz com que o `uniq` retorne a quantidade de ocorrências de cada linha:

```
find ./  | awk -F"/" '{if ($2) { print $2 } else { print $1 } }' |sort |uniq -c
```

Só lembrando que este comando também retornará os arquivos que estiverem no diretório atual. Se quiser somente os diretórios, use `find ./ -type d`.

---

Já para o seu comando completo, acho mais fácil fazer um  `for`  nos resultados do `find`, aí você pode executar os comandos que quiser:

```
for dir in $(find ./ -regex '\./.*_.*\.\(doc\|docx\|md\|xls\)$' | awk -F"/" '{if ($2) { print $2 } else { print $1 } }'|sort|uniq )
do
    status=$(stat -c "%.10w;%.10y;$(dirname "$dir");$(basename "$dir")" "$dir") 

    if{something}
    etc....
done
```

A cada iteração do `for`, a variável `$dir` será o nome de um dos diretórios encontrados. Dentro do `for` fica mais fácil executar quantos comandos você quiser, sem precisar colocar `$()` dentro de outro, juntar com *pipes*, etc. Acredito que assim fica mais simples e claro.

Se bem que no exemplo acima, como você está usando `dirname` e `basename`, nem precisaria do `awk` depois do `find`. Mas enfim, usando um `for` nos resultados do `find` te permite colocar quantos comandos quiser, e eu acho mais fácil do que a forma que você está tentando. O `-exec` eu costumo usar quando é para executar um único comando simples, para coisas mais complexas eu prefiro o `for` mesmo.

---

Se quiser usar o `awk` dentro do `for`, conforme seu [último comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/372118/sa%C3%ADda-inesperada-ao-imprimir-substring/372156#comment741092_372156):

```
for dir in $(find ./ -regex '\./.*_.*\.\(doc\|docx\|md\|xls\)$' 
do
    status=$(stat -c "%.10w;%.10y;$(dirname $dir | awk -F"/" '{if ($2) { print $2 } else { print $1 } }');$(basename "$dir")" "$dir") 
    echo $status
done
```

Se algum dos arquivos/diretórios tiver espaço no nome, basta setar a variável `IFS` antes do `for`:

```
IFS=$'\n'

for dir ...
```

Com isso, o `for` considera as quebras de linha (e não mais o espaço) como separador dos seus registros, tratando nomes de arquivos e diretórios com espaços como se fossem uma coisa só.

Para restaurar o valor original da variável, sugiro guardá-lo antes da alteração:

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for dir ....
....

IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: hkotsubo, quando eu encapsulo esse comando com `$()` para jogar seu resultado pra uma variável, ele não interpreta o pipe `|`... sabe dizer oq pode ser isso??

Comment: @GabrielHardoim Testei aqui: `resultado=$(find ./  | awk -F"/" '{if ($2) { print $2 } else { print $1 } }' |sort |uniq )` - funcionou, se fizer `echo $resultado` vai ver o resultado impresso. Se não for isso, vc pode editar a pergunta e colocar o comando que vc está tentando rodar...

Comment: `awk -F"/" '{if ($2) { print $2 } else { print $1 } }'` === `awk -F/ '{print $(NF)}'`

Comment: @fedorqui Isso só é verdade se tiver no máximo dois campos. Se o diretório for `./a/b/c/d/e/f`, `$NF` vai pegar o `f`, mas o AP quer o `a` nesse caso

Comment: Isso é verdade. Não está claro para mim exatamente o que é o AP procurando. Diretório contendo alguma coisa? Talvez `grep -l` funcione melhor? (sorry, I am using google translate)

Comment: @hkotsubo Editei a pergunta com o comando que estou utilizando.. ficou mais claro desse jeito?

Comment: @GabrielHardoim Atualizei a resposta

Comment: @hkotsubo ficou um pouco mais claro, porém eu coloco o `awk` depois do `dirname` e não depois do `find`

Comment: @GabrielHardoim Coloquei o `awk` depois do `dirname` e o resultado muda sim. Atualizei a resposta

Comment: @hkotsubo só me resta uma questão... quando o `find` retorna um diretório com espaço no nome (`/um exemplo/arquivo.txt`) o `for` meio que divide o nome.. como faço para contornar isso??

Comment: @GabrielHardoim Atualizei novamente a resposta :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo Muito obrigado cara!!

Answer (score 2):

Acho que com `awk` dá pra fazer o que você quer:

```
$ find .
.
./bbb
./bbb/bbb.txt
./aaa
./aaa/aaa.txt
./ccc
./ccc/ccc.txt

(pegando so' os arquivos)
$ find . -type f | awk -F/ ' { print $2 }'
bbb
aaa
ccc

$
```

Comment: cool!!  Talvez `find . -type f | awk -F/  '{ print $(NF-1) }'`